# generic stack implementation in linux core

Tags: c, linux, stack

I am writing a patch to bcache Linux module and struggle to find generic LIFO implementation in Linux core. I have found several FIFO implementations both on [defines](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/bcache/util.h#L118) and [without](https://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/lib/kfifo.c). However, nothing alike for LIFO.

Where can one find one? Preferably C not asm and not based on defines, but any should work.

If no abstract LIFO is provided, what are the easiest structures to implement LIFO on (generic stack realization in Linux core for instance)?

Comment: An array plus an index is maybe too trivial to generalize ?

Comment: "*not based on defines*" - how else would you implement a generic data structure in C? you want "virtual methods" with function pointers? I wouldn't put that overhead in the kernel.

Comment: @wildplasser I guess that is going to be my next move. I can't get rid of the feeling that I am re-inventing a bicycle, LIFO is so widely used that it _has_ _to_ _be_ in Linux core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LIFO has fixed maximum depth, and is not dynamically allocated, then it is simply something like

```
#define LIFO_MAXDEPTH  16

static spinlock_t   lifo_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
static size_t       lifo_count = 0;
static struct item  lifo_entry[LIFO_MAXDEPTH];

int lifo_push(const struct item *from)
{
    spin_lock(&lifo_lock);
    if (lifo_count >= LIFO_MAXDEPTH) {
        spin_unlock(&lifo_lock);
        return -1;
    }

    lifo_entry[lifo_count++] = *from;

    spin_unlock(&lifo_lock);
    return 0;
}

int lifo_pop(struct item *to)
{
    spin_lock(&lifo_lock);
    if (lifo_count < 1) {
        spin_unlock(&lifo_lock);
        return -1;
    }

    *to = lifo_entry[--lifo_count];

    spin_unlock(&lifo_lock);
    return 0;
}
```

Because we only need to keep it locked for very short durations, a spinlock should suffice.

If the LIFO is dynamically allocated, things get more complicated. In particular, because we might have to call `kmalloc()` or `kfree()`, we cannot use a spinlock. You'd also want to split the stack into page-sized chunks, since higher-order allocations may fail. Then you must consider things like nefarious users trying to use the facility for DOS attacks, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. Unfortunately, the depth is only known at runtime (since depth of the stack depends on block size and cache size and can be huge). BTW, all synchronization is already written via mutex in bcache module, I only need to play around the LIFO itself - push, pop, peek, clean and so on.